# easylist global properties

Tags: easylist

I generally use easylist in the following manner

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\begin{document}

    \begin{easylist}
    \ListProperties(Progressive*=3ex, Start1=1)
       @ item1
       @ item2 
       @ item3 
    \end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

every time, I have to set the list property by using `\ListProperties(Progressive*=3ex, Start1=1)`, is there a way to set a global property for all the easylist entries, instead of repeating the properties every time I declare an easylist entry?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you turned your code into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill, thanks for letting me know, I have updated the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just specify the `\ListProperties` before any `easylst` environment:

[image]

Note that each `easylist` continues on from the last one.

If you want each instance of `easlylist` to have the same properties at the start, then you can redefine the `easylist` environment as in the code below to apply the specified `\ListProperties` and the start of each invocation of the environment:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Progressive*=3ex, Start1=1)

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
   @ item1
   @ item2 
   @ item3 
\end{easylist}

\bigskip

\begin{easylist}
   @ item1
   @ item2 
   @ item3 
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `\renewenvironment`

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}


\let\OldEasylist\easylist
\let\OldEndEasylist\endeasylist
\renewenvironment{easylist}{%
    \OldEasylist%
    \ListProperties(Progressive*=3ex, Start1=1)%
}{%
    \OldEndEasylist%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
   @ item1
   @ item2 
   @ item3 
\end{easylist}

\bigskip

\begin{easylist}
   @ item1
   @ item2 
   @ item3 
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro of `etoolbox` and do:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{easylist}
        {\ListProperties(Progressive*=3ex, Start1=2,Style*=\color{green!60!black})}
        {}
        {}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{easylist}
        {\ListProperties(Progressive*=3ex, Start1=2,Style*=\color{green!60!black})}
        {}
        {}

\begin{document}
One list
    \begin{easylist}    
       @ item1
       @ item2
       @ item3
    \end{easylist}
Another list    
    \begin{easylist}
       @ item1
       @ item2
       @ item3
    \end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]