# Easy list; creating new style

Tags: easylist

Creator of macro `Easylist` is @ereg ([Easylist inside adjustwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442284/easylist-inside-adjustwidth/442294#442294))

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newbox\Easylist@box
\newenvironment{Easylist}
{\par\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}%
\setbox\Easylist@box=\vbox\bgroup
\dimen@=\@totalleftmargin
\@parboxrestore
\leftskip=\dimen@
\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd
\begin{easylist}}
{\end{easylist}\xdef\Easylist@tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
\unvbox\Easylist@box\par\prevdepth\Easylist@tpd}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed,
Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm,
Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm,
Style1*=\textbullet\hspace{0.25cm},%
Style2*=$\circ$\hspace{0.25cm},%
Style3*=\tiny$\blacksquare$\hspace{0.25cm},%
Style4*=\tiny$\square$\hspace{0.25cm})

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{}
    \begin{Easylist}
        & First thingy
        && Second thingy
        &&& Third thingy
        &&&& Fourth thingy
    \end{Easylist}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

I have found in `easylist` documentation predefined styles which are used by command `\begin{easylist}[<Style>`. So as I have understood it is possible to create multiple style and easily change from one to another. Im interested in creating two new style so I can easy shift from one to another. Can you give me example how to create new stlye like shown in picture. Thank you very much! :)

For now I'm using command `\ListProperties` but when I want to change the style inside document is pretty difficult.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out form the documentation a method to easily define your own styles, but you can adapt the solution from [Define custom named easylist styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375832/4301) to define your custom styles. Below, I define four styles:

```
\definemyeasylist{lowercasestyle}{Numbers=l}
\definemyeasylist{uppercasestyle}{Numbers=L}
\definemyeasylist{romanlowercasestyle}{Numbers=R}
\definemyeasylist{romanuppercasestyle}{Numbers=R}
```

which yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375832/4301
\def\definemyeasylist#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname myeasylist@style@#1\endcsname{\NewList(#2)}}
\def\myeasylist{\futurelet\next\domyeasylist}
\def\domyeasylist{\ifx[\next\expandafter\domyeasylistone\else\expandafter\domyeasylistnop\fi}
\def\domyeasylistone[#1]{\begin{easylist}\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\csname myeasylist@style@#1\endcsname\fi}
\def\domyeasylistnop{\begin{easylist}\NewList}
\def\endmyeasylist{\end{easylist}}

\definemyeasylist{lowercasestyle}{Numbers=l}
\definemyeasylist{uppercasestyle}{Numbers=L}
\definemyeasylist{romanlowercasestyle}{Numbers=r}
\definemyeasylist{romanuppercasestyle}{Numbers=R}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{myeasylist}[enumerate]
        & dog
        & cat
        & rabbit
    \end{myeasylist}
    \par\medskip
    \begin{myeasylist}[lowercasestyle]
        & dog
        & cat
        & rabbit
    \end{myeasylist}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
    \begin{myeasylist}[romanuppercasestyle]
        & dog
        & cat
        & rabbit
    \end{myeasylist}
    \par\medskip
    \begin{myeasylist}[romanlowercasestyle]
        & dog
        & cat
        & rabbit
    \end{myeasylist}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help! My MWE would produce this https://ibb.co/k54JpJ. With function `\definemyeasylist` is it possible to define something like this : `\ListProperties(Hide=100,Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed,
Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm,
Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm`

Comment: @Beginner: The answer here is to change the styles to obtain the dried results of the image in your question. In this particular list of properties case you have `Hide=100` set which means to not display the counters. Try removing that and see if that is what you desire.  So, defining `\definemyeasylist{mystyle}{Hang=true,FinalSpace=0.5cm,Align=fixed, Margin1=0.5cm,Margin2=1.5cm,Margin3=2.5cm,Margin4=3.5cm, Margin5=4.5cm,Margin6=5.5cm,Margin7=6.5cm,Space=0.15cm,Space*=0.15cm}` along with a desinred `Numbers=x`(See p. 5 of the manual)  setting should give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried using this code and it's working well except it is not compatibile with macro from @ereg. I have post new question if you can help I would appreciate. :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442698/combining-two-macros