# How to make easylist always start from 1? And few other things

Tags: easylist

I did find how to make `easylist` always start from 1 in [this Q](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162857/easylist-global-properties).

```
\let\OldEasylist\easylist
\let\OldEndEasylist\endeasylist
\renewenvironment{easylist}{%
    \OldEasylist%
    \ListProperties(Start1=1)%
}{%
    \OldEndEasylist%
}%
```

However it doesn't work as I would like it to, if I need a unsorted list, doing `\begin{easylist}[itemize]` doesn't work as expected, `[itemize]` is printed on top of the list.

Something like this:

[itemize]

1. item1
2. item2
3. ...

Also the indenting doesn't work, if I use that piece of code. E.x. I normally can do `\indent\begin{easy...` to indent it under a `subparagraph` but if I add that snipet, it doesn't move.

So in short, how can I make `easylist` always start from 1, without it breaking bunch of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer for the `itemize` issue.

As noted in the [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162859/) to the linked question, the package `etoolbox` has a command to modify environments called `\AtBeginEnvironment`, which does basically the same as the code in the question but it preserves the properties of the original environment better, in this case regarding options given at the start of the environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{easylist}{\ListProperties(Start1=1)}
\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}
& an item
&& another item
& second item
\end{easylist}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{easylist}
& an item
&& another item
& second item
\end{easylist}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
& an item
&& another item
& second item
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

For the indentation issue I'm not fully sure what your input and your preferred output is. You could add this to the question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that answer before. As for the indenting, it fixed itself when I used the `etoolbox`, so I will let it be.